# Travel from dusseldorf to UK by Train

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I want to know can I travel from dusseldorf to UK by train for 1 day only I only have valid Schengen visa.

If yes, what would be the procedure

Thanks

Comment: What is your nationality?  A Schengen visa will not get you into the UK, not even for one day.

Comment: Indian nationality

Answer (score 5):

Citizens of India need a visa to visit the UK.  https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/tourism/no

There isn't any exception if you only visit for one day, or if you come by train, or if you already have a Schengen visa.  None of that is relevant.  You would need a visa.

Comment: What about Transist without visa clause if I would travelling by air and have ticket back(leaving UK ) to my work place 23:59hrs.

Comment: I am traveling to dusseldorf for business related work have Ctype visa

Comment: You still need a standard UK visitor visa, I believe the Visitor In Transit visa is not applicable in this case because you are not arriving by plane. It's possible if you are flying from Dusseldorf to somewhere else then you can go through Heathrow (but not leave the airport) without a visa, that's a different question I am not sure about that.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/tourism/yes/yes

Comment: If above case is valid if my family send invite letter if he is staying in UK than is it possible?

Comment: @Taher The case mentioned by you assumes you have an article 10 residence card (which you don't). Unless your spouse is an EU national and you have an EU residence card and you are travelling with them, you will need a visa to enter the UK.

Comment: I have a cousin in UK with UK citizenship so he can send invite letter and article 10 ?

Comment: So whether he inviting me would be OK ?

Comment: @Taher He can invite you but you will need a visa as said in the answer. To avail visa free service _you_ need to have a residence card in _your_ name (along with other requirements already mentioned in my earlier comment). Your cousin's card (if he has one) is useless.